# Is molecular weight of proteins additive?

Tags: concentration

I have an elementary question regarding calculation of molecular weight of a complex of two proteins. Essentially, I have two proteins binding as

$$\ce{A + B <=> AB}$$

I have the concentration of [A] and [B] in ng/ml, which I can convert to nM using its molecular weight (available in kDa). I have only concentration of [AB] in ng/ml, but I am not able to convert that into nM. Is the assumption that molecular weight of [AB] is equal to sum of molecular weights of [A] and [B] correct assumption?

I am not able to see the intuition behind this logic, and if someone can help me here, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The molecular mass in Dalton, amu or whichever unit you prefer is equivalent to the molar mass $M$ in $\mathrm{g/mol}$ that chemists prefer to use for this discussion. Both are strictly additive. The molar mass of a larger complex is the sum of the molar masses of all its components.

This is because of how the unit is defined. Focussing on molecular mass, we could see ot as *mass of a molecule*. The mass of a molecule is put together by adding the masses of the atoms that this molecule is made up of. If that molecule now forms larger aggregates, the mass of the resulting thing (still a single ‘thing’ albeit larger) is the sum of the masses of its constituents. And so on.

You just need to beware in case you have aggregates that are not strictly $\ce{AB}$. Consider two proteins that form an $\ce{AB2}$ complex: In this case $M(\ce{AB2}) = M(\ce{A}) + 2 \cdot M(\ce{B})$, because we have two $\ce{B}$ in the final complex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for editing the question. I tried to see if MW was additive using the example of $$\ce{NaCl}$$ and it turned out to be additive. Wasn't so sure about large proteins though, thanks!